# Automatically append given text to the result from a formula

Tags: string, excel, formatting, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have the following formula:

```
=$AF$46
```

How would I append text to its result?

e.g., if `=$AF$46` is showing up as `0.00`, how would I make it show `0.00% done`?

<sup>Editor's note: The question was later extended to "restrict" formatting of the formula's result to 2 decimal places. Some answers predate this requirement; others cover either of the two possible interpretations of "restrict": "up to 2 decimal places" and "exactly 2 decimal places".</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add text via a formula like the following (if you place this in a different cell than `AF46`):

```
=AF46 & "% done"
```

Comment: Any idea how to restrict AF46 to 2 decimal places within the formula?

Comment: You could do that by using the `ROUND`function. Try changing the formula to this: `=ROUND(AF46,2) & "% done"`.

Comment: Be careful, numbers like 1 would show up as '1' not '1.00'.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe just use custom formatting:

```
#,##0.00"% done"
```

(preserves value in case required for further calculation).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `TEXT` excel function like:

```
=TEXT(AF46,"#0.00") & "% done"
```

The second argument '#0.00' to the TEXT function is an [Excel format code](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/number-format-codes-HP005198679.aspx).
This will ensure that Af46 is displayed in the right format.  Simply using AF46 in the formula could lead to things like '0.3333333333 % done', rather than formatted to 2 decimals.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with the CONCATENATE function

```
=CONCATENATE($AF$46,"% done")
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the concatenate function.

`=CONCATENATE($AF$46,"% done")`